# Permission denied using "man"

Tags: permissions, manpage

For some reason an Ubuntu server (14.04.4 LTS) I'm working on will not allow "man" to be run by regular user.  Example:

```
man ls
man: can't change directory to '/root': Permission denied
man: command exited with status 255: (cd /root && LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page ls(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page ls(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$ MAN_PN=ls(1) pager -s)
```

How might this have happened and more importantly how can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

Seems this only occurs after I `su user` where "user" is a non privileged user.  Workaround is to `su -l user` but I still don't understand why `man` would become a privileged command without the login flag.

Comment: Whats the output of `type -a man`?

Comment: @heemayl `man is /usr/bin/man`

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $MANPATH`?

Comment: @heemayl - no output for that (an empty string)

Comment: What about `echo $MANPAGER` and `echo $PAGER` (when `su`'d to `user`)?

Comment: And how about ls -ld /usr/bin/man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently in the folder `/root`.

`man` runs some command including `cd <current folder>`. In this case that is `cd /root` (compare the 2nd line of the error). But that is not allowed for non-root user.

The following will work:

```
cd ~ && man ls
```

To reproduce the same behaviour you can do this:

```
$ sudo su
# cd /root
# su normal_user
$ man ls
man: can't change directory to '/root': Permission denied
```

Comment: thanks.  any idea why man is doing `cd .`?  What would be the point of that?

Comment: i have no clue, sorry.